# How to specify date only in angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker, angular-bootstrap

It seems to insist on making you choose a time also.  I went through the read me several times and I'm not seeing how to only do a date.

https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Why not just use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker?

Comment: You need to add the directive mentioned here, to format the date-time. https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#formatting-the-date-in-an-input-box

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `minView` to `day` in the config `datetimepicker-config="{'minView':'day'}"`. It restricts selection till that level. So, by making it `day`, we won't let it select further `day`s. Like this:

```
<datetimepicker ng-model="date" datetimepicker-config="{'minView':'day'}" />
```

That should do it!